# How do I put results in list and sort it out before print?

Tags: python

I have an animation-related problem. To quickly find number of frames that will loop perfectly within animation sequence, I need to know what round divisions of total number of frames are.

I found a code that finds all round divisors of a number, and it's doing it's job, but I also need to sort it by value.

```
import math
 
# method to print the divisors
def printDivisors(n) :
     
    # Note that this loop runs till square root
    i = 1
    while i <= math.sqrt(n):
         
        if (n % i == 0) :
             
            # If divisors are equal, print only one
            if (n / i == i) :
                print (i,end=" ")
            else :
                # Otherwise print both
                print (i , int(n/i), end=" ")
        i = i + 1
 
# Driver method
frames=int(input("Enter a number of frames you have: "))

print ("The divisors for the number of frames you have: ")
printDivisors(frames)
 
#Original code is contributed by Nikita Tiwari.
```

To sort results I tried to use list and sort functions, but seems like I don't know what I'm doing, because list seems to be not updated.

```
import math
buffer_list = []

# method to print the divisors
def printDivisors(n) :
     
    # Note that this loop runs till square root
    i = 1
    while i <= math.sqrt(n):
         
        if (n % i == 0) :
             
            # If divisors are equal, append to list only one
            if (n / i == i) :
                buffer_list.append(i)
            else :
                # Otherwise append to list both
                buffer_list.append(i , int(n/i))
        i = i + 1
 
# Driver method
frames=int(input("Enter a number of frames you have: "))

print ("The divisors for the number of frames you have: ")

# Sort and print list
buffer_list.sort()
print (buffer_list)

#Original code is contributed by Nikita Tiwari.
```

Comment: In the second code snippet, the function `printDivisors` is never called, so your `buffer_list` stays empty the whole time.

Comment: You also have invalid syntax here: `buffer_list.append(i, int(n/i))`, There should only be one argument

Comment: You should rename the function, since it no longer prints anything.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For future reference, please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. It's a good idea to be able to sanity-check your own code first, to avoid [making incorrect assumptions about the actual cause of the problem](https://xyproblem.info). Aside from the fact that `.append` only appends *one* value (if you want to append both `i` and `n/i`, make two separate calls), there is nothing fundamentally wrong with your approach. The only problem is that you still need to *call* the function, just as you did before the change.

Comment: As an aside, please note that this is *not a discussion forum* - we don't want "decorations" on a post with conversational language, talking about your level of experience ("Noob question"), etc. Questions asked here aren't just for OP; they're for people who find it later with a search engine. We want Stack Overflow to look, from the outside, like a FAQ built by the community - *because it is*. I edited the post title accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to call the `printDivisors` function, so no items are being added to your list. The sorting code itself is fine.

I've fixed your code below. I changed `printDivisors` to `calculateDivisors`, as it is not actually printing anything. I also fixed the second `buffer_list.append` call, as `append` only takes one argument.

```
import math

buffer_list = []

def calculateDivisors(n):
    i = 1
    while i <= math.sqrt(n):
        if (n % i == 0):
            if (n / i == i):
                buffer_list.append(i)
            else:
                buffer_list.append(n // i)
        i = i + 1
 
frames = int(input("Enter a number of frames you have: "))
calculateDivisors(frames)
print("The divisors for the number of frames you have: ")
buffer_list.sort()
print(buffer_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

- Instead of modifying a global list, return it from your function.
- Instead of a `while` loop, use a `for` loop.
- `list.append` only takes a single argument.
- Instead of `int(n / i)` use integer division: `n // i`
- You don't need to sort the list, you already know that `i` is increasing and `n // i` is decreasing. You just need to make sure that the latter are reversed.
- I agree with Jack Taylor that you want to change the name of the function.
- I'll add type annotations for clarity.
- You don't need to check for `n // i == i` every iteration, since it can only happen at the last iteration.

Here is a possible solution:

```
import math

def divisors(n: int) -> list[int]:
    small_divisors = []
    large_divisors = []
    sqrt_n = int(math.sqrt(n))
    for i in range(1, sqrt_n):
        if n % i == 0:
            small_divisors.append(i)
            large_divisors.append(n // i)
    if n % sqrt_n == 0:
        small_divisors.append(sqrt_n)
    return small_divisors + large_divisors[::-1]

frames = int(input("Enter a number of frames you have: "))

print("The divisors for the number of frames you have:")
print(divisors(frames))
```